# Is It Ever Good Practice To Modify The Index Variable Inside a FOR Loop?

Tags: c#

Given the code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            // Do work
        }
```

Is is ever acceptable to change the value of `i` from within the loop?
For example:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            if( i == 2)
            {
               i = 4;
            }
            // Do work
        }
```

Comment: Unless you can present a good use case, no, how could it? If you have a good use case, we'll talk ;)

Comment: Generally considered as bad practice. But sometimes...

Comment: I don't think its ever "good", but sometimes, "good" isn't a priority.

Comment: I didn't have a good case for asking this. I was maintaining some legacy code that modified the iterator from within the for loop and it kind of threw me for a loop(no pun intended!) That's what prompted me to post the question. My belief is to NOT do it but I wanted to get a feel from the developer community. - Thanks to all who took the time to weigh in on this topic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my opinion, it is too confusing. Better use a `while` loop in such case.

Comment: Agree, it is about intent. The intent of a for loop is in its declaration, it starts at 0, ends at 42, and increments by 2. You don't expect it to do something completely different in the middle of its existence.

Comment: I don't know if there is any strict "right" answer to this question. Some may argue that it is a question of style. But I agree that it does add confusion.

Answer (score 7):

It is acceptable, however, I personally think this should be avoided.  Since it's creating code that will be unexpected by most developers, I find that it's causing something much less maintainable.

Personally, if you need to do this, I would recommend switching to a while loop:

```
int i=1;
while (i <= 5)
{
    if (i == 2)
        i = 4;

    ++i;
}
```

This, at least, warns people that you're using non-standard logic.

Alternatively, if you're just trying to skip elements, use [continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    if (i == 2 || i == 3)
       continue;
}
```

While this is, technically, a few more operations than just setting `i` directly, it will make more sense to other developers...

Comment: I agree. I avoid this in my code as I think it makes it difficult to read. When I see a for loop I expect the code inside it to be executed once for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

**YES**

You see that frequently in apps that parse data.  For example, suppose I'm scanning a binary file, and I'm basically looking for certain data structures.  I might have code that does the following:

```
int SizeOfInterestingSpot = 4;
int InterestingSpotCount = 0;
for (int currentSpot = 0; currentSpot < endOfFile; currentSpot++)
{
    if (IsInterestingPart(file[currentSpot])
    {
        InterestingSpotCount++;
        //I know that I have one of what I need ,and further, that this structure in the file takes 20 bytes, so...
        currentSpot += SizeOfInterestingSpot-1;  //Skip the rest of that structure.

    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd find this more understandable as a while loop.

Comment: It may very well be;  but I don't feel its incorrect or wrong as a FOR loop.

Answer (score 3):

An example would be deleting items which match some criteria:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); /*nothing*/)
{
    if (pred(array[i]))
        i++;
    else
        array.erase(array.begin() + i);
}
```

However a better idea would be using iterators:

```
for (auto it = array.begin(); it != array.end(); /*nothing*/)
{
    if (pred(*it))
        ++it;
    else
        it = array.erase(it);
}
```

---

**EDIT**
Oh sorry, my code is C++, and the question is about C#. But nevertheless the idea is the same:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; /*nothing*/)
{
    if (pred(list[i]))
        i++;
    else
        list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

And a better idea might be of course just

```
list.RemoveAll(x => !pred(x));
```

Or in a slightly more modern style,

```
list = list.Where(pred);
```

(here `list` should be `IEnumerable<...>`)

Comment: If you need to write a loop to remove items from a list, the idiomatic way is with a `for` loop going over the items in reverse. That way, no change needs to be made to the indexing variable.

Comment: @Jeff Well, sometimes you just need to go from the beginning. For instance, you might be gathering some data for output in the same loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, but only in a specific cases.

It may be a bit confusing - if I set `i=4` will it be incremented before the next iteration or not?

It may be a sign of a code smell - maybe you should do a LINQ query before and only process relevant elements?

Use with care!

Comment: This question came up when I was maintaining some legacy code. In my case LINQ is not an option. - Good points

Answer (score 1):

*Yes it can be. As there are an extremely enormous amount of possible situations, you're bound to find one exception where it would be considered good practice.*

But stopping the theoretica lside of things, i'd say: **no**. Don't do it.
It gets quite complicated, and hard to read and/or follow. I would rather see something like the `continue` statement, although i'm not a big fan of that either.

Comment: +1 It seems to me to take away from the purpose of the for loop as by nature the code within it should be executed a set number of times.

Answer (score 1):

An example could be a `for` loop where you want in a certain condition to repeat current iteration or go back to a previous iteration or even skip a certain amount of iterations (instead of a numered `continue`).

But these cases are rare. And even for these cases, consider that the `for` loop is just one means among `while`, `do` and other tools that can be used. so consider this as bad practice and try to avoid it. your code will also be less readable that way.

So for conclusion: It's achievable (not in a `foreach`) but **strive to avoid this** using `while` and `do` etc. instead.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would say that if the logic of the algorithm called for a normally-linearly-iterating behavior, but skipping or repeating certain iterations, go for it. However, I also agree with most people that this is not normal for loop usage, so were I in your shoes, I'd make sure to throw in a line or two of comments stating WHY this is happening.

A perfectly valid use case for such a thing might be to parse a roman numeral string. For each character index in the string, look at that character and the next one. If the next character's numeric value is greater than the current character, subtract the current character's value from the next one's, add the result to the total, and skip the next char by incrementing the current index. Otherwise, just add the current character's value to the running total and continue.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Petar Minchev:

> In my opinion, it is too confusing.
>   Better use a while loop in such case.

And I would say by doing that, you must be aware of some things that could happen, such as infinite loops, premature-canceled loops, weird variable values or maths when they are based on your index, and mainly (not excluding any of the others) execution flow problems based on your index and other variabes modified by the fail loop.

But if you got such a case, go for it.

Answer (score -3):

This is really crude, but searching it out is how i got here, my thoughts for changing the index would be as a retry function.

```
    //Keep in mind i made this up and typed it on my phone
var images = new ImaginaryListOfPicsThatsAlreadyFull();
int RetryCount = 0;
for(int i = images.Count-1; i > =0;i--)
{
    RetryCount++;
    if(RetryCount > 3) //Limit it to 3 tries
        throw new Exception("MaxRetryException");
    try
    {
        DoInconsistentTask(images[i]); //connect to a server hosted on wifi maybe? 
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        i++; //increase the index and continue the loop to do the same entry
        continue;
    }
    RetryCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Is this not a valid case where you could use this?

Comment: The question posed was "is it good practice to change the counter inside of a loop". A valid answer would be "yes" or "no", not "here's an example of where you could do that". That being said, the question is also off-topic, and is now closed. It'll likely be deleted entirely in a few days.