# String output gives weird letters

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "Too many tags";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        if(!(isspace(s[i]))){
            s[i] = '#' + s[i];
        }
    }
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make a program which adds # tag before each letter in the string, but on output I get weird letters.. where is my mistake?

Comment: `s[i] = '#' + s[i];` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s[i] = '#' + s[i];
```

modifies the value of an existing character.  If you want to add new characters into your string, you should use [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert):

```
s.insert(i, "#");
```

As Mark Ransom points out, you also need to move one further char through your string to avoid constantly adding "#" before the same letter.  You could do this using

```
s.insert(i++, "#");
```

Note that you could always take VladimirM's advice and make slightly larger changes to something like

```
int i=0;
while (i<s.size()) {
    if (!isspace(s[i])) {
        s.insert(i++, "#");
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I think if you do that without modifying the loop you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly?  You need to use double quotes around the #.  If you did that, you could always try `s.insert(i++, 1, '#');` instead.

Comment: A small note: changing a loop variable inside for-loop is usually considered as a bad practice [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996638/is-it-ever-good-practice-to-modify-the-index-variable-inside-a-for-loop) because of some confusion. It is better to use while-loop if you are going to change a loop-variable inside the loop.

Comment: @VladimirM I was aiming for minimal change from the OP's code.  Your point is good however so I've added a note of a solution in that style now.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
s[i] = '#' + s[i];
```

isn't doing what you think it is. `s[i]` is a `char`, `#` is also a `char`. Adding these together doesn't give you the concatenation of the two characters, it gives you the addition of the integer code of the characters (so 35 for `#` and the ASCII code for whatever `s[i]` happens to be).

Comment: And how do I fix that, any alternative ways?

Answer (score 2):

I add more: I think the simpler way is to use temporary variable otherwise your loop with 'insert' will go to endless loop and will hang:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "Too many tags";
    string res = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        if(!(isspace(s[i]))){
            res += "#";
        }
        res += s[i];
    }
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```